# Regex: Grab text inside my tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, nunjucks

I'm working on NodeJS read text inside files, But I don't know much about regex for grabbing string, So i'm asking for help.

**Example text:**

`text text {{ 'translate me' | lang }} text {{ 'A' | replace('A', 'B') }} {{"another text"|lang}}`

I want to grab text inside Only {{ '*SOMETHING*' | lang }}

**Output**

`['translate me', 'another text']`

So, how to use Regex for grab, thanks.

Oh, Also it should support some spacing case like

- {{ 'translate me' | lang }}
- {{'translate me'|lang}}
- {{ 'translate me'  |lang}}
- {{'translate me' | lang }}

Also Support " and ' (single and double quote)

- {{ "translate me" | lang }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two opening curlies, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by the quoted string, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by `|`, `lang` and two closing curlies, using (new) lookbehind:

```js
const text = "text text {{ 'translate me' | lang }} text {{ 'A' | replace('A', 'B') }} {{ 'another text' | lang }}";
console.log(text.match(
  /(?<=\{\{ *')[^']+(?=' *\| *lang *}})/g
));

// or, without lookbehind:

const re = /\{\{ *'([^']+)(?=' *\| *lang *}})/g;
let match;
const matches = [];
while ((match = re.exec(text)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Apologies, I have one more case, about ' and " like, {{ "translate me" | lang }}

Comment: Match `'` or `"` and give the main captured string negative lookahead for that character `/\{\{ *(['"])(((?!\1).)+)(?=\1 *\| *lang *}})/g`